# Auto complete a HTML file from a form

Tags: php, html, forms, auto-generate

Quick question to see how this would be done as I'm not sure if it can be.

But essentially, I have to make 50 "profile pages" for some new mortgage brokers.

I was wondering if it is possible to create a form with basic details (say name, email, phone, credit rep details, photo etc...) and on submit it generates those fields into the designated section in a HTML file.

Just was trying to work out a way to speed it all up, over manually re-coding each page.

Cheers

Comment: most sites would put them in a database then populate a template with those values on request -NOT create a septate html file for each. your profile says your a "Web Developer" you should really know this

Comment: The answer is: Yes.  (For a more specific answer, please ask a more specific question).

Comment: This is more or less how all CMS systems work: you have a html template describing the page layout, a database storing information and an engine that mixes both ...

Comment: There are way too many possibilities for this and this question is a little too  broad. I understand that you are simply asking, but try and narrow your question to something a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, SO if you want it just for that instance, say, I enter my details and the new profile page just displays all the data. That can be extremely easy. Just create in template profile page and place the variable posted by the form and you are done.

Now, if you want that the data from the form should be saved and could be retrieved the next time or anytime:

1. You need to save the form entries in the database.
2. I believe there must be some sort of identification by which a specific profile could be opened say email address or something, that could be enter later on to fetch the data for profile of any specific person.
3. Perform database query to fetch the saved info of particular user and place it in the template html file you have.

There is no point of creating 50 files for 50 profiles. :)

Feel free to ask any question .